# set PageHeading in controller with m dash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I need to use `&mdash` (more beautiful as par my UI/UX designer), instead of regular '-' .

My question is how do I jam this html dash `&mdash` inside my controller where I am setting my `pageHeading` and `BrowserTitle`.

I am working with an MVC application, the code below is the controller which gets the result and then bundles up and sends it to the view.

In the View the `PageHeading` comes up automatically:

```
public ActionResult View()
{
  var dto = _service.GetByID(id);
  base.BrowserTitle = "Reports - " + report.ReportDisplayName;
  base.PageHeading = "Reports - " + report.ReportDisplayName;

  return View(dto);
}
```

Comment: Use a `MvcHtmlString` or in your razor page, if it is just a normal string, use the html helper `@Html.Raw()`

Comment: Is there a way to do it in controller?

Comment: Convert those properties into `MvcHtmlString` so when they are used they will be output as html

Comment: Just copy and paste an em dash character into the string; no need for an entity if you're using UTF-8 or some other reasonable code page. Here's the character: — Oh, yeah, they add an en dash before my name. Adding this to make sure it's not confusing :)

Comment: Heretic Monkey  thanks